# how is it calculated?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know why the answer of this script is

```
var h1Array = $('h1').first().text().split(' '),
                        h1Last = h1Array[h1Array.length-1],
                        answerElem = $('#jschl_answer');

                    answerElem.val(22+14*10);
                    answerElem.val(parseInt(answerElem.val())+(h1Last.substr(0,h1Last.length-1)).length);
```

what is the sum of this? i know that 10*14 = 140 + 22 = 162 but why in this case the sum is 179

so from where we got the extra 17?

Another example

```
var h1Array = $('h1').first().text().split(' '),
                        h1Last = h1Array[h1Array.length-1],
                        answerElem = $('#jschl_answer');

                    answerElem.val(46+36*8);
                    answerElem.val(parseInt(answerElem.val())+(h1Last.substr(0,h1Last.length-1)).length);
```

sum = 347 while the sum of answerElem.val(46+36*8); is actually equals to 334 so from where we got the extra 13?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: It seems to come from `h1Last.substr(0,h1Last.length-1)).length`, whatever it is.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I think your comment is misleading.

Comment: @undefined take it up with Maynard

Comment: `(h1Last.substr(0,h1Last.length-1)).length`? What's wrong with just `h1Last.length` ?

Comment: the length of the last word of the first H1 element?

Comment: @a man in love, you really need to specify what is in this mysterious last "h1" tag? I'm guessing the last word has 17 characters in it.

Answer (score 4):

```
answerElem.val(22+14*10); // 162
answerElem.val(
  parseInt(answerElem.val()) + // 162
  (h1Last.substr(0,h1Last.length-1)).length // guess this must be 17
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the length of the last token, tokenized by " ",

- from the text value

  - of the  first() field

    - of the element named "h1"